# How to soap api authenticate with certification using Spyne in Python

Tags: python, web-services, soap, spyne

I am new to the soap api with python, And I am using the [spyne](https://github.com/arskom/spyne). That I need to access the soap api with certification (.crt file). Is there any way to access soap api with ".crt" file or any other libraries available for python to access the shop with secure server.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to use Spyne as a client? Spyne is not too good at that. You mean you need to authenticate using a client SSL certificate when using soap via HTTP? Spyne doesn't support it

Comment: Thanks! [Burak Arslan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1520211/burak-arslan)